# wizard progress oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

A demo page is prepared where the Wizard container is used within one page. So we move step by step on a single page.I dont know how to do this becouse it forces me for each step to move to next page so how to do all steps witouth moving to nwxtpage.

i tried to make a list and to asign each step on same page id butwhan i do it it automaticly goes to last step an i cant move .so i expect A demo page is prepared where the Wizard container is used within one page. So we move step by step on a single page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wizard is just a list region where every list entry is a step in the wizard. To make it work in a single page you could:

- Create a page item Px_WIZARD_STEP in your page
- Use the same page as target for each step in the wizard, but set Px_WIZARD_STEP to the value of the target step
- Change "List Entry Current for Pages Type" list attribute to type "Expression" and set it to Px_WIZARD_STEP = #step number#
- The next and previous buttons in the wizard should just point to the same page with a different value for the Px_WIZARD_STEP page item.

Comment: 3. A demo page is prepared where the wizard container has a dynamic number of steps, Tuesday using query. and can you help me wit this thank you very much

Comment: You are asking a very vague question... I have no idea what answer you are expecting or how to answer. I don't know what "3. A demo page.. " means. I have no idea what "Tuesday using query" means.

Comment: A list can be dynamically created. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmdb/creating-dynamic-lists.html#GUID-1B67A3C8-39FA-4868-9532-F68AFCD74651) is the documentation.
Before you do that however, I'd suggest you familiarize yourself with the concept of a wizard on a single page using a static list and using the technique I described above. Once you master that, make your list dynamic.

Comment: i need a wizard with dynamic number of steps using sql query can you walk me trough how to do it?

Comment: Hmm... no I can't give you step by step instructions, just guide you in the right direction. You'll have to do the work. If the nr of pages is not always the same in a wizard, then use a branch on each page to go the the relevant next page.

Comment: just one more thing friend what is the best way to reset wizard step so that it resets every time i run the aplication for exammple if i left the wizard on step two and exit the app and run it again it would stay on second step so is there way to clear cache on run of an appication or some other way

Comment: If you access the wizard through a branch or a link or a menu step then you can use the "clear cache" attribute of the link builder. set it to the page number of your wizard.

Comment: Pls consider marking the question as answered

Comment: i want wizard step to reset to 1 every time i run the page where my wizard is located

Comment: I can't tell you how do do something with no information whatsoever on how you have built it. I would suggest asking a new question instead and provide as much info as possible. Is this on a single page or multiple pages ? do you have a page item that controls the step of the wizzard ? etc etc. You are the only one who has access to your app and who knows how this is built. if you want help on something then start by describing exactly what you have, what behaviour you're seeing and what behaviour you're expecting.

Comment: its a single page multiple step wizard i have a page item that controls the step of the wizard i made processes when clicing on next to :P2_WIZARD_STEP := :P2_WIZARD_STEP + 1; and for previous :P2_WIZARD_STEP := :P2_WIZARD_STEP - 1;  and it works but if i lets say stay on second step and exit the application and then run it again it stays on second step so i just want when running app again to restart it to first step basicly when i run the app i want it always to start from first step and not to remember if i left it on some other step when i run it os whenever i run it i want to start from 1

Comment: This is my last answer in this thread. Comments are not for followup questions - that doesn't work very well. 
To solve your issue: reset the cache when the page is run as I explained earlier.  That should reset page item P2_WIZARD_STEP. You could also a add a computation to set P2_WIZARD_STEP to 1 if it is NULL or set the value of P2_WIZARD_STEP step to 1 as part of the url